# Javascript files not being read in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

Can someone please help me out? all my JavaScript files are not being read in my WordPress theme, even though they are en-queued properly and i have used the jQuery no conflict method. They are simply not working. I checked the console there are no errors. Also tried emptying the browser's cache still nothing. I'm creating my own theme. What can i do?

```
 function wpps_theme_styles() {
    wp_register_script( 'wppsmodernizr',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1-respond-1.4.2.min.js', '','',false );
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrapmin',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'plugins',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/plugins.js' , array('jquery'), '',true);
    wp_register_script( 'app',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/app.js' , array('jquery'), '',true);
    wp_register_script( 'formwizard',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/pages/formsWizard.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'custom',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/pages/custom.js', '', '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js', '', '', '' );

    wp_enqueue_script('wppsmodernizr');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapmin');
    wp_enqueue_script('plugins');
    wp_enqueue_script('app');
    wp_enqueue_script('formwizard');        
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');        
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpps_theme_styles');
```

Comment: You could try posting more details, this isn't quite enough to diagnose the issue. Are your scripts showing up at all when you view source? Do you have `wp_head` and `wp_footer` in your templates?

Comment: can you please add enqueued functions, header.php & footer.php to clarify more. If possible please add a live demo to see more.

Comment: A common mistake is that the javascript code interacts with DOM elements which not loaded at time of execution. In those cases you have to execute your javascript only when the whole [DOM is loaded](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or you include your javascript files in footer instead of header..

Comment: yes i do have wp_head in my header.php and wp_footer in my footer.php. And in my all my templates i have get_header()  at the top and get_footer() at the bottom. The CSS is perfectly fine, just the JavaScript.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch all files are loading in the footer.

Comment: Maybe you have a link to your site? As has been said, it is difficult to debug code without code ;)

Comment: I've edited my question and included th function where I'm enqueueing scripts.

Comment: "All files are loading in the footer" - you mean if you view the page source, you see them there?  Or are you just talking about the `wp_register_script` `$in_footer` argument?  If the latter - can you see them in the page source?

Comment: Actually i can not see them in the page source...I used wp_footer just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a problem with the javascript not running, it's a problem with the scripts making it into the page in the first place.  Any chance you're using a child theme?  If so, try `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: By the way - you've got a mismatch in your handles: `formwizard` and `formwiz`.  And that script depends on `custom.js` - is that script enqueued somewhere (with that handle)?

Comment: No I am not using a child theme.

Comment: ok thanks for tha @Hobo. i fixed it but still nothing. i checked my console now im getting the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined
app.js?ver=4.6.1:429 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function

Comment: That sounds like the files are now being enqueued (check your page source again) - maybe you need to add a dependency on `jQuery` in your `wp_register_script()` calls?

Comment: still nothing in source 
:(. im baffled

Comment: When you say nothing in the source, you mean none of the 3 files are in the source (modernizr would be in the header, not the footer)?  Where's `app.js` (the error you mentioned) getting enqueued?  Do you have any errors in your server's PHP logs?

Comment: Aaargh. The dependencies are case sensitive - for `bootstrap.min.js`, it should be `jquery`, not `jQuery`

Comment: Did you have any luck based on the latest changes/comments on my answer?

Comment: hey @Hobo, truly sorry for the late feedback, but i havent had any luck, despite all the changes. I'm really baffled

Comment: No worries.  Are you still getting the same error?  What file is `slimScroll` in (you should just be able to search the content of all the files for it)?

Comment: slimScroll is in app.js

Comment: It's called in app.js (that's what the error says); it's declared there too?  Maybe it's an ordering problem in the file.  Is the site online anywhere I can see it?  If not, can you zip up the theme and put it somewhere I can download it?  I know it's not ideal, but it might make things quicker if I can see the code

Comment: Thanks for the code; see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on your latest update, and the error message, here are a few comments.  This won't necessarily solve your problem, but there's too much to add as a comment.  Please update the question with any new error messages (either console errors or PHP errors).

First, don't add your own version of jquery.  WordPress has one built in, so use that (see the "Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress" section of [the wp_enqueue_script documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)).  It's possible part of the problem is caused by reusing the built-in handle, or maybe that the path you used looks wrong (it's missing a / before the js folder name).

Secondly, if you're not using a parameter, but need to pass a value, use the default from [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).  I don't know if this is causing any problem, but I'd err on the side of caution.  So if there are no dependencies, use `array()` for that parameter; and if you're not providing a version, use `false`.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the code. I've set it up (activated the theme and the plugins).  I wasn't seeing any error in the console, then I realised you'd commented out `app` and `plugins` in the source.  I uncommented them, then I got a different error to the one you mentioned: `$(...).wysihtml5 is not a function`.  I searched the source, and can't find any other reference to `wysihtml5`, so I commented out that line just to test.

Same thing happened with `$('.select-chosen').chosen({width: "100%"});`, so I commented it out.

`$('.select-select2').select2();` failed too.  There seems to be some code for that in the category-posts plugin, but I can't find it being enqueued anywhere, so I commented that out too.

`$('.input-slider').slider();` failed as well.  I don't know what slider you're expecting to use, so I added the built-in `jquery-ui-slider`, and made `app` dependent on it.  If you're using a different slider you'll have to enqueue the script and/or make `app` dependent on the script that contains it.

`$('.input-tags').tagsInput({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto'});` - commented it out.  There's no other reference to it.

`$('.input-datepicker, .input-daterange').datepicker({weekStart: 1});` - added `jquery-ui-datepicker`.  Same comments apply as for slider

Commented out the blocks referencing `timepicker` and `easyPieChart`.  There are no other references to them.

**TL;DR**

You seem to be missing the source for quite a few functions `app.js` depends on.  I commented out lines 86-93, 98-99, and 105-117 of `app.js`, and added dependencies to pull in the jQuery UI slider and datepicker.  That stops the errors in the console, though I have no idea if it'll fix your problem - it depends on whether you need the commented out functionality, and which slider and datepicker you want to use.  Presumably you know where to get the code you need.

At least the original problem is solved - all the js files are in the page source.

If you want me to check anything else, I'll probably need a database dump.  I'm using the content from a default WordPress installation, and it's possible I'd need your content to see exactly what's going on.

One other thing - you seem to have an unmatched PHP tag somewhere.  When I view the source, I see `?>` before the content.

Here's my latest `wpps_theme_styles()`

```
function wpps_theme_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrapcss', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'plugins', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/plugins.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'themes', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/themes.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'custom_themes', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/custom.css' );
    //wp_register_style( 'googlefonts' ), ;

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss');
    wp_enqueue_style('maincss');
    wp_enqueue_style('plugins');
    wp_enqueue_style('themes');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom_themes');
    //wp_enqueue_style('googlefonts','');



    wp_register_script( 'wppsmodernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1-respond-1.4.2.min.js', array(),                         false, false );

    wp_register_script( 'bootstrapmin',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',                     array('jquery'),                 false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'app',           get_template_directory_uri().'/js/app.js',                                      array('jquery', 'bootstrapmin', 'plugins', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-ui-datepicker'), false, true);

    wp_register_script( 'plugins',       get_template_directory_uri().'/js/plugins.js',                                  array('jquery'),                 false, true);
    wp_register_script( 'formwizard',    get_template_directory_uri().'/js/pages/formsWizard.js',                        array('jquery'),                 false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'custom',        get_template_directory_uri().'/js/pages/custom.js',                             array('jquery'),                 false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Built in version
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable'); // Built in version
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider'); // Built in version
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker'); // Built in version

    wp_enqueue_script('wppsmodernizr');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapmin');
    wp_enqueue_script('app');

    wp_enqueue_script('plugins');
    wp_enqueue_script('formwizard');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');
}
```

Comment: Ok i pasted in your code. im getting:  
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function           app.js?ver=4.6.1:429

Comment: OK, looking at [this page](https://tamarasupport.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/integrating-jquery-slimscroll-to-your-website/), you'll also need "jQuery UI (Draggable)", so I've added that (it's also built into WordPress).  Assuming you've downloaded slimScroll and it's in the plugins script, I've added a dependency on plugins for app.  If that's not right (slimScrool isn't in plugins), you should adjust the dependency to the script slimScroll _is_ in, or add it (if it's not in any existing script).

Comment: Ok. Let me update it. Will definitely keep you updated

Comment: Thanks @hobo. I ended up using a different form Wizard altogether. It appears as if the code for the wizard i was using had some errors. I much appreciate hour help! :)

Comment: No problem.  Glad you got a solution that worked for you

Comment: And then I used your solution on another theme that had the same problem! everything is working perfectly! :) thanks again

Comment: Great news.  No problem - thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this by replace this code

```
function wpps_theme_styles() {
wp_register_script( 'wppsmodernizr',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1-respond-1.4.2.min.js' );
wp_register_script( 'bootstrapmin',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',array('xyz'), 'false', 'true' );
wp_register_script( 'formwizard',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/pages/formsWizard.js', array('custom.js'), 'false', 'true' );
        wp_enqueue_script('xyz');        
        wp_enqueue_script('wppsmodernizr');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapmin');
        wp_enqueue_script('formwiz');

    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpps_theme_styles');
```

Comment: Won't the bootstrap script be looking for a dependency with a handle of `xyz`, which doesn't exist?  And so fail to load?

Comment: could it be because of how i'm handling this script?? i had put it in my custom.js and has replaced the dollar sign with 'jQuery':      <script>$(function(){ FormsWizard.init(); });</script>

Comment: Where's `custom.js` being registered and enqueued?  And how does it relate to `app.js` that you mention in your comment showing your error message?  Where's that being registered and enqueued?

Comment: custom.js and app.js are enqueued in function wpps_theme_styles. custom.js is not related at all to app.js. app.js came with the original bootstrap template, then custom is my own js file that i put to include the script that initializes the form wizard, which was included at the very bottom of the page

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw your comment.  Thanks for the clarification.  custom.js and app.js aren't enqueued in the version of wpps_theme_styles in your question.  Can you edit the question and put the current version please?